# Rendering a template inside a django view?

Tags: python, django

So I'm designing a website with Django that does some heavy scraping based on user input. 
This can take up to 5-6 secs and while I am working on cutting that down I would like for some kind of a loader to show up while the backend is scraping.

I have put a loader as you normally would using CSS and JavaScript inside the template but that only pops up when the template is actually loading and not when the view is scraping to gather data for the template.

Tried this in Django:

```
def scrape(request):
    render(request,'loader.html')

    *do scraping*
    return render(request,'results.html',scraped_data)
```

Comment: One solution is to render the page before scraping. Make an ajax function  call it on _document.ready()_  (i.e. when the page loads). in your function append a loader at the screen then hit your URL where you will do scraping while the loader is on the screen, When ajax call returns in the **success** function, disable the loader and display your data

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not really familiar with AJAX but I did some quick research and what you said makes a lot of sense. Will definitely try doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I would use to solve this is to fire an async function within the scrape view.

```py
@shared_task
def do_the_needful():
    return "hello I am doing the needful"

def scrape_result(request, scrape_id):
    result = AsyncResult(scrape_id).get()
    # convert result to json or some other web format
    return result_as_json

def scrape(request):
    scrape_request_id = do_the_needful.submit()
    return render(request, "scrape.html", context={"scrape_request_id": scrape_request_id}
```

Then within the HTML you'll need to create some Javascript which will perform Ajax requests to the **scrape_result** view using the **scrape_request_id** in the context.